# How do I get the image that I took and submit it to my server

Tags: android, android-camera, android-file

Currently I am able to upload an existed image in the sdcard to my server.  I'm a total newbie in Android programming world and I was wondering how do I dynamically grab the newly taken image and submit it to the server?

This is what I have so far for my onClick event

```
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            camera.takePicture(myShutterCallback, 
                    myPictureCallback_RAW, myPictureCallback_JPG);

            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {

                    File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "nypdImages");
                    //hard code
                    String path = mediaStorageDir.getPath() + "/" + "IMG_20000106_124322.jpg";

                    int response= uploadFile(path);
                    System.out.println("RES : " + response);                        
                }
              }).start();   

        }});
```

This is the codes for my camera functions

```
    ShutterCallback myShutterCallback = new ShutterCallback(){

    @Override
    public void onShutter() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }};

PictureCallback myPictureCallback_RAW = new PictureCallback(){

    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] arg0, Camera arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }};

PictureCallback myPictureCallback_JPG = new PictureCallback(){

    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] arg0, Camera arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        FileOutputStream outStream = null;

        try 
        {
            File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "nypdImages");

            if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) 
            {
                if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) 
                {
                    Log.d("nypdImages", "Oops! Failed create " + "nypdImages" + " directory");
                }
            }

            String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
            String path = mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator + "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg";


            outStream = new FileOutputStream(String.format(path, System.currentTimeMillis()));
            outStream.write(arg0);
            outStream.close();

            sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()))); 
        } 
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally 
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Image Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //VuzixCamera.super.onBackPressed();
        }

        camera.startPreview();
    }};
```

Comment: I would first store the image in a folder, then read it to send to your server using an Http post request.

Comment: have u knowledge of php?if yes i can provide u a sample program

Comment: Yes, I have knowledge of php.  What's this has anything to do with php?  I've already used php to handle incoming data and submit it to my server and it's in working condition.  I just want `"IMG_20000106_124322.jpg"` to be dynamic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this answer will help you.

Take A new Picture Code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;

public class CameraUtil  extends Activity {

    private final static int REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO=200;
    private final String TAG = "Camera";

    String mCurrentPhotoPath;
    String path;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if(! isDeviceSupportCamera()){
            Log.e(TAG,"Camera Not Supported");
            Intent returnFromCameraIntent = new Intent();
            setResult(RESULT_CANCELED,returnFromCameraIntent);     
            finish();
        }
        else{
            dispatchTakePictureIntent();
        }

    }

     private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
        Log.i(TAG,"Dispatch Take Picture Intent");

        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent       
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            // Create the File where the photo should go      
                File photoFile = null;
                try{
                    photoFile = createImageFile();
                }catch (IOException ex) {
                    // Error occurred while creating the File
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                    Log.i(TAG,"Error occurred while creating the File");
                }
                // Continue only if the File was successfully created
                if (photoFile != null) {
                    //  fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);  
                    takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
                    startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
                }       
        }
     }


        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            Log.i(TAG,"On Activity Result");
            File file= new File(path);  

            if (requestCode == REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO  && resultCode == RESULT_OK && path!=null && file.length()>0) {
                        Intent returnFromCameraIntent = new Intent();
                        returnFromCameraIntent.putExtra("picturePath",path);
                        setResult(RESULT_OK,returnFromCameraIntent);  
                        finish();
                        Log.i(TAG,"Camera Closed");
                }else{
                    Log.i(TAG,"On Result CANCEL");
                    // cancelled Image capture
                    try{
                    /*delete Temperory created file*/  
                        file.delete();
                    }catch(Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    Intent returnFromCameraIntent = new Intent();
                    setResult(RESULT_CANCELED,returnFromCameraIntent);     
                    finish();
                    Log.i(TAG,"Image Capture Cancelled");
           }
           galleryAddPic();
     }

     private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
            String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss",Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
            String imageFileName = "CAMERA_" + timeStamp + "_WA0001";

            File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                     + File.separator + "MyApp"+ File.separator);

            if(!root.exists()){
                    root.mkdirs();  
            }

           // File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
           //         Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
            File image = File.createTempFile(
                imageFileName,  /* prefix */
                ".jpg",         /* suffix */
                root      /* directory */
            );
            // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
            mCurrentPhotoPath = "file:" + image.getAbsolutePath();
            path=""+image.getAbsolutePath();
            return image;
    }

     private void galleryAddPic() {
            Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
            File f = new File(mCurrentPhotoPath);
            Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
            mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
            this.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
     }

     private boolean isDeviceSupportCamera() {
            if (getApplicationContext().getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)) {
                // this device has a camera
                return true;
            } else {
                // no camera on this device
                return false;
            }
     }
}
```

Choose Existing Picture Code:

```
import java.io.File;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;

public class GalleryUtil extends Activity{
    private final static int RESULT_LOAD_GALLERY=100;
    public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE = 1;
    private static final String TAG = "Gallery_Image";

    String mCurrentPhotoPath;
    File photoFile = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        try{
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_GALLERY); 
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
         super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
         Log.i(TAG,"On Activity Result");        
         if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_GALLERY && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();

                Intent returnFromGalleryIntent = new Intent();
                returnFromGalleryIntent.putExtra("picturePath",picturePath);
                setResult(RESULT_OK,returnFromGalleryIntent);     
                finish();

           }else{
                Log.i(TAG,"Image Capture Cancelled");
                Intent returnFromGalleryIntent = new Intent();
                setResult(RESULT_CANCELED,returnFromGalleryIntent);     
                finish();
           }
    }
}
```

Convert Image to Base64 String:

```
public class Base64Utils {

    private static final String TAG = "Base64Utils";
    private String picturePath;
    private String base64;

    public Base64Utils(String picturePath) {
        this.picturePath = picturePath;
    }

    public String getPicturePath() {
        return picturePath;
    }
    public void setPicturePath(String picturePath) {
        this.picturePath = picturePath;
    }

    public String getBase64() {
        FileInputStream fis11=null;
            try {
                fis11 = new FileInputStream(picturePath);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            ByteArrayOutputStream bos11 = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            byte[] buf = new byte[8096];
            try {
                for (int readNum; (readNum = fis11.read(buf)) != -1;) {
                    bos11.write(buf, 0, readNum); 
                }
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        bytes = bos11.toByteArray();
        base64 = Base64.encodeToString(bytes, Base64.DEFAULT);  
        return base64;
    }

    public void setBase64(String base64) {
        this.base64 = base64;
    }
}
```

Main Activity Code: Choose or Take Picture, convert it to base64 string and Send Base64 String to Server.

```
public class CapatureImage extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private final String TAG = "CapatureImage";
    String picturePath;
    String base64 = null,   
    private ImageButton image;
    // for popup
    private PopupWindow pop;

    private final int GALLERY_ACTIVITY_CODE = 200;
    private final int CAMERA_ACTIVITY_CODE = 300;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.CapatureImage);
        configureComponent();
    }

    private void configureComponent() {
        image = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.image);
        image.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.image:
            initiatePopupWindow();
            break;
        case R.id.button_camera_dialog:
            Intent camera_Intent = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(),
                    CameraUtil.class);
            pop.dismiss();
            this.startActivityForResult(camera_Intent, CAMERA_ACTIVITY_CODE);
            break;

        case R.id.button_gallery_dialog:
            Intent gallery_Intent = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(),
                    GalleryUtil.class);
            pop.dismiss();
            this.startActivityForResult(gallery_Intent, GALLERY_ACTIVITY_CODE);
            break;

        case R.id.button_cancel_dialog:
            pop.dismiss();
            break;

        case R.id.button_remove_dialog:
            Log.i(TAG, "Remove Picture");
            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_781q);
            picturePath=null;
            pop.dismiss();
            break;
        }
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (requestCode == GALLERY_ACTIVITY_CODE) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                picturePath = data.getStringExtra("picturePath");   
                base64 = new Base64Utils(picturePath).getBase64();   
                //send this base64 string to server
            }
            if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                // Write your code if there's no result
            }
        }
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_ACTIVITY_CODE) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            //  Log.i("Camera_Activity", data.toString());
                picturePath = data.getStringExtra("picturePath");
                base64 = new Base64Utils(picturePath).getBase64(); //send this base64 to server
            }
            if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                // Write your code if there's no result
            }
        }
    }// onActivityResult

    public void initiatePopupWindow() {
        try {
            // We need to get the instance of the LayoutInflater
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) EngineerStatus_Update.this
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialoge_choosephoto,
                    (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.photo_popup));
            if (picturePath != null && !picturePath.isEmpty()) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Image Exist..Add Remove Button");
                remove = (Button) layout
                        .findViewById(R.id.button_remove_dialog);
                remove.setOnClickListener(this);
                remove.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                pop = new PopupWindow(layout,
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, true);
            } else {
                Log.i(TAG, "No Image..remove  Remove Button");
                remove = (Button) layout
                        .findViewById(R.id.button_remove_dialog);
                remove.setOnClickListener(this);
                remove.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                pop = new PopupWindow(layout,
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, true);
            }

            // component for popup
            gallery = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.button_gallery_dialog);
            gallery.setOnClickListener(this);
            camera = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.button_camera_dialog);
            camera.setOnClickListener(this);
            cancel = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.button_cancel_dialog);
            cancel.setOnClickListener(this);
            pop.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    void displayImage(String path) {
        File imgFile = new File(path);
        if(imgFile.exists()){
            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
            image.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
            image.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        }   
   }
}
```

Comment: Vuzix SmartGlasses does not 'support' ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE.  I have to use Surfaceview

Answer (score 0):

there is two classes upload and main_activity.And i here put it's xml file

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    final static int CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
    private static final String TAG = "CaptureImage.java";
    public static ImageView showImg = null;
    static String uploadFilePath = " ";
    static String Path;
    static int delete_image_id = 0;
    static TextView imageDetails = null;
    // FeedReaderDbHelper mDbHelper = new FeedReaderDbHelper(CaptureImage.this);
    static Cursor cursor = null;
    public ProgressDialog dialog_upload = null;
    public String s_name;
    public String s_Adress;
    int serverResponseCode = 0;
    TextView shift_display;
    Uri imageUri = null;
    OnClickListener oclBtnOk = new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.i("VALUES", "It is Working");
            String fileName = "Camera_Example.jpg";
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, fileName);
            values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION,
                "Image capture by camera");

            imageUri = getContentResolver().insert(
                MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);

            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);

            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 1);

            startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);

            /*************************** Camera Intent End ************************/

        }
    };
    MainActivity CameraActivity = null;
    Upload upload;
    Button outlet_names_show;
    double latitude;
    double longitude;
    OnClickListener oclBtnOk3 = new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (showImg.getDrawable() == null) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, " Picture was not captured ",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                upload_prescription();
                // CallSummery.flag_bt_merchan=true;

            }

        }
    };
    private Button buttonback;

    /**
     * ********* Convert Image Uri path to physical path *************
     */

    public static String convertImageUriToFile(Uri imageUri, Activity activity) {

        int imageID = 0;

        try {

            /*********** Which columns values want to get *******/
            String[] proj = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA,
                MediaStore.Images.Media._ID,
                MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID,
                MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.ORIENTATION};

            cursor = activity.getContentResolver().query(imageUri, proj, null,
                null, null);

            // Get Query Data

            int columnIndex = cursor
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID);
            int file_ColumnIndex = cursor
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);

            // int orientation_ColumnIndex = cursor.
            // getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.ORIENTATION);

            int size = cursor.getCount();

            /******* If size is 0, there are no images on the SD Card. *****/

            if (size == 0) {

                // imageDetails.setText("No Image");
            } else {

                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {

                    imageID = cursor.getInt(columnIndex);
                    delete_image_id = imageID;

                    Path = cursor.getString(file_ColumnIndex);

                }

            }

        } finally {
            if (cursor != null) {
                cursor.close();
            }
        }

        // Return Captured Image ImageID ( By this ImageID Image will load from
        // sdcard )

        return "" + imageID;
    }

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        MainActivity.this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        CameraActivity = this;
        showImg = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.showImg);
        upload = new Upload(MainActivity.this);
        final Button photo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.photo);
        final Button upload = (Button) findViewById(R.id.upload);


        photo.setOnClickListener(oclBtnOk);
        upload.setOnClickListener(oclBtnOk3);



    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        if (imageUri != null) {
            outState.putString("cameraImageUri", imageUri.toString());
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        if (savedInstanceState.containsKey("cameraImageUri")) {
            imageUri = Uri
                .parse(savedInstanceState.getString("cameraImageUri"));
        }
    }

    public void upload_prescription() {
        dialog_upload = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "",
            "Uploading file...", true);




        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {

                    }
                });

                createDirectoryIfNeeded();




                upload.uploadFile(uploadFilePath);

            }
        }).start();

    }







    private void createDirectoryIfNeeded() {
        File direct = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + "/Capturetemp");

        if (!direct.exists()) {
            if (direct.mkdir()) {
                // directory is created;
            }

        }

    }


    public void copy(String lo, String lan) throws JSONException {

        String sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();

        Random ran = new Random();

        uploadFilePath = sdCard + "/Capturetemp/" + ran.toString() + ".jpg";

        File sourceLocation = new File(Path);
        File targetLocation = new File(uploadFilePath);
        Log.v(TAG, "sourceLocation: " + sourceLocation);
        Log.v(TAG, "targetLocation: " + targetLocation);

        try {

            // 1 = move the file, 2 = copy the file
            int actionChoice = 2;

            // moving the file to another directory
            if (actionChoice == 1) {

                if (sourceLocation.renameTo(targetLocation)) {
                    Log.v(TAG, "Move file successful.");
                } else {
                    Log.v(TAG, "Move file failed.");
                }

            }

            // we will copy the file
            else {

                // make sure the target file exists

                if (sourceLocation.exists()) {

                    InputStream in = new FileInputStream(sourceLocation);
                    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(targetLocation);

                    // Copy the bits from instream to outstream
                    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
                    int len;

                    while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
                        out.write(buf, 0, len);
                    }

                    in.close();
                    out.close();

                    Log.v(TAG, "Copy file successful.");

                } else {
                    Log.v(TAG, "Copy file failed. Source file missing.");
                }

            }

        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            // e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {

            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                /*********** Load Captured Image And Data Start ***************/

                String imageId = convertImageUriToFile(imageUri, CameraActivity);

                // Create and excecute AsyncTask to load capture image

                new LoadImagesFromSDCard(MainActivity.this).execute(""
                    + imageId);

                /*********** Load Captured Image And Data End ****************/

            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {

                Toast.makeText(this, " Picture was not taken ",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } else {

                Toast.makeText(this, " Picture was not taken ",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

    }

    public class LoadImagesFromSDCard extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

        Context context;
        Bitmap mBitmap;
        private ProgressDialog loadingdailog;

        public LoadImagesFromSDCard(MainActivity context) {
            this.context = context;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            loadingdailog = new ProgressDialog(context);
            loadingdailog.setMessage("Loading Image.....");
            loadingdailog.show();

        }

        // Call after onPreExecute method
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... urls) {

            Bitmap bitmap = null;
            Bitmap newBitmap = null;
            Uri uri = null;

            try {

                uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(
                    MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, ""
                        + urls[0]);

                /************** Decode an input stream into a bitmap. *********/
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver()
                    .openInputStream(uri));

                if (bitmap != null) {

                    /********* Creates a new bitmap, scaled from an existing bitmap. ***********/

                    newBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 350, 350,
                        true);
                    // SaveIamge(newBitmap);
                    bitmap.recycle();
                    if (newBitmap != null) {

                        mBitmap = newBitmap;
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // Error fetching image, try to recover

                /********* Cancel execution of this task. **********/
                cancel(true);
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {

            if (loadingdailog.isShowing() && loadingdailog != null) {

                loadingdailog.dismiss();
                loadingdailog = null;
            }

            if (mBitmap != null) {
                showImg.setImageBitmap(mBitmap);

            }
        }
    }


}
```

upload class

```
public class Upload {
    protected MainActivity context;
    ProgressDialog dialog = null;
    int serverResponseCode = 0;
    String uploadFilePath = null;
    String uploadFileName = null;
    String msg = null;
    String upLoadServerUri = "http://fileuploadpath";


    public Upload(MainActivity context) {
        this.context = context;

    }

    public int uploadFile(String sourceFileUri) {

        String fileName = sourceFileUri;

        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        DataOutputStream dos = null;
        String lineEnd = "\r\n";
        String twoHyphens = "--";
        String boundary = "*****";
        int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
        byte[] buffer;
        int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
        File sourceFile = new File(sourceFileUri);

        if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {

            return 0;

        } else {
            try {
                FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(
                    sourceFile);




                URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);
                conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
                conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
                conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");


                conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                    "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
                conn.setRequestProperty("photo", fileName);


                //      conn.setRequestProperty("session_id","13");

                dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
                dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"photo\";filename=\""
                    + fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);

                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);


                // create a buffer of maximum size
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();

                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

                // read file and write it into form...
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

                while (bytesRead > 0) {

                    dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                    bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                    bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                    bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

                }

                // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

                // Responses from the server (code and message)
                serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
                String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();

                Log.i("uploadFile", "HTTP Response is : "
                    + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);

                try {

                    readStream(conn.getInputStream());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                if (serverResponseCode == 200) {

                    context.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            context.dialog_upload.dismiss();
                            Toast.makeText(context, "File Upload Complete.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                    });

                }
                fileInputStream.close();
            } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
                // Toast.makeText(context, "File Upload Not Complete.",
                // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.e("Upload file to server", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
            } catch (Exception e) {

                // context.dialog.dismiss();
                e.printStackTrace();
                // Toast.makeText(context, "File Upload Not Complete.",
                // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.e("Upload file to server Exception",
                    "Exception : " + e.getMessage(), e);
            }
            // context.dialog.dismiss();
            return serverResponseCode;

        }
    }

    private void readStream(InputStream in) {
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        try {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            String line = "";
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                Log.e("tag", line);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (reader != null) {
                try {
                    reader.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

xml file

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:weightSum="1" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/showImg"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:contentDescription="bla bla" />



    <Button
        android:id="@+id/photo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"

        android:text="Capture Image"
        android:textSize="26sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/upload"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"

        android:text="Upload Photo"
        android:textSize="26sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

for image uri you should paste your file upload path

Comment: Is there any way to combine the 2 button into one?